# How can I deploy the newest tagged image from ECR using Drone, during an ECS deploy step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, drone.io

I've been trying to figure this out for a little while. Thanks to helpful previous answers from others, I've been able to make some progress in this, but I'm unfortunately a little stuck in the deploy step.

Summary: Does Drone have a way of sharing parameter expanded variables between steps? Or, is there a simple way to add ECR commands into the fabfuel/ecs-deploy plugin, or other ecs-deploy step?

The Story: We have a Ruby image getting pushed to ECR via Drone as part of another repo deployment, which is used in this repo's Drone deployment. Previously we'd been using ruby-latest tags, which had worked fine to effectively hard-code the image name, which made it easy to push from one repo, and use in the other. This makes it difficult to do rollbacks or change-overs using task definitions though, since each container's image only uses ruby-latest (instead of the Drone commit hash). I'd like to update this process to using the Drone commit hash, but need a way to communicate that back to the other repo that needs to deploy the Ruby image as well.

What I've tried: I'm able to get the newest proper image name and commit hash using the aws-cli in another step

```bash
export IMAGE_NAME=123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/service:`aws ecr describe-images --repository-name service --output text --region us-east-1 --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].imageTags[0]' | tr '\t' '\n' | grep ruby | head -3 | tail -1`
```

echoing IMAGE_NAME shows the proper name is being set in the aws-cli step. The problem is when doing the actual deploy in another step (using fabfuel/ecs-deploy image), this IMAGE_NAME variable is not available (because the variables are scoped between pipeline steps).

```yaml
  - name: ecs-deploy
    image: fabfuel/ecs-deploy
    pull: if-not-exists
    privileged: true
    commands:
      - ecs deploy prod service --region us-east-1 -i service $IMAGE_NAME --timeout 1500
```

I've tried adding the above, export IMAGE_NAME=... into the commands section, right above the ecs-deploy step, but unfortunately the aws cli (including ecr commands) is not available in the fabfuel/ecs-deploy plugin image.

Just wondering if I'm missing something obvious, any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the *best* solution, but it turned out to be the **simplest** solution that didn't require editing the image and maintaining a separate version of said public image.

```yaml
# Install AWS CLI, so we can query ECR, since it's not present in the image
- apk update && apk upgrade && apk add aws-cli
```

This then allows using the aws ecr command above to query for the most recently pushed image that matches the specified tag. Hopefully this helps someone else that's struggling with a similar issue!